# Does a dispatch group block the main thread in iOS?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatchgroup

I'm calling some code to query and update the CallKit call extension, and very occassionally I've seen a hang and the call is timing out. I thought I'd put this off the main thread so that it wouldn't be blocking the UI, but is that actually not the case?

The UI is blocking up, I don't know if its this code below, or something else.

Here's the query function:

```
    private func queryCallExtensionStatusWithDispatchGroup() {
        let dg = DispatchGroup()
        dg.enter()
        self.doQueryCallExtensionStatusWithDispatchGroup(dispatchGroup: dg)
        Logger.trace(TAG + "queryCallExtensionStatusWithDispatchGroup() WAITING .... ")
        let dispatchTimeoutResult = dg.wait(timeout:  DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(30))
        if dispatchTimeoutResult == .timedOut {
            Logger.info(TAG + "queryCallExtensionStatusWithDispatchGroup() TIMED OUT")
        } else {
            Logger.trace(TAG + "queryCallExtensionStatusWithDispatchGroup() LEFT")
        }
    }


private func doQueryCallExtensionStatusWithDispatchGroup(dispatchGroup:DispatchGroup)  {
<snip>
    dispatchGroup.leave() 
}
```

And its invocation:

```
private let callExtensionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.appname.serialQueue")

...
callExtensionQueue.async {
    self!.queryCallExtensionStatusWithDispatchGroup()
}
```

Comment: The call to `wait` blocks whatever thread you call it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet will block the worker thread used by `callExtensionQueue`, not the main thread.

So, unless you have some `sync` dispatches to `callExtensionQueue` elsewhere (or some unusual thread explosion scenario), the above will not block the main thread.

Your problem likely rests elsewhere.

---

In cases where you want to make sure you do not accidentally call a function from the main queue, you might add a [`dispatchPrecondition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1780605-dispatchprecondition/), so you will get a warning in debug builds if you accidentally call this function from the main queue:

```swift
private func queryCallExtensionStatusWithDispatchGroup() {
    dispatchPrecondition(condition: .notOnQueue(.main))

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    doQueryCallExtensionStatus {
        group.leave()
    }
    logger.trace("\(#function) WAITING .... ")
    let result = group.wait(timeout: .now() + .seconds(30))
    if result == .timedOut {
        logger.info("\(#function) TIMED OUT")
    } else {
        logger.trace("\(#function) LEFT")
    }
}
```

As an aside, in the above, rather than passing the dispatch group to the called function (unnecessarily entangling these two functions), the standard technique is a completion handler closure parameter (and you can make it optional, if you want):

```swift
private func doQueryCallExtensionStatus(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    …
    completion?()
}
```

That way, all of the `DispatchGroup` related code is isolated to a single function, `queryCallExtensionStatusWithDispatchGroup`.